# Why is MemAvailable a lot less than MemFree+Buffers+Cached?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory-usage, debugging

I'm running a Linux workstation without swap and I have installed [`earlyoom`](https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom) daemon to automatically kill some processes if I'm running out of RAM. The `earlyoom` works by monitoring kernel `MemAvailable` value and if the available memory gets low enough, it kills less important processes.

This has worked fine for a long time but suddenly I'm now running into situation where `MemAvailable` is suddenly really low compared to the rest of the system. For example:

```
$ grep -E '^(MemTotal|MemFree|MemAvailable|Buffers|Cached):' /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       32362500 kB
MemFree:         5983300 kB
MemAvailable:    2141000 kB
Buffers:          665208 kB
Cached:          4228632 kB
```

Note how MemAvailable is much lower than `MemFree`+`Buffers`+`Cached`.

**Are there any tools I can run to further investigate why this happens?** I feel that the system performance is a bit worse than normally and I had to stop the `earlyoom` service because its logic will not work unless `MemAvailable` is stable (that is, it correctly describes the available memory to user mode processes).

According to https://superuser.com/a/980821/100154 MemAvailable is an estimate of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. As I have no swap, what is this supposed to mean? Is this supposed to mean the amount of memory a new process can acquire before OOM Killer is triggered (because that would logically hit "the swap is full" situation)?

I had assumed that `MemAvailable` >= `MemFree` would be always true. Not here.

**Additional info:**

Searching around the internet suggests that the cause may be open files that are not backed by the filesystem and as a result, cannot be freed from the memory. The command `sudo lsof | wc -l` outputs `653100` so I definitely cannot manually go through that list.

The top of the `sudo slabtop` says

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 10323895 / 10898372 (94.7%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 404046 / 404046 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 104 / 136 (76.5%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 6213407.66K / 6293208.07K (98.7%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.58K / 23.88K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
4593690 4593656  99%    1.06K 153123       30   4899936K ext4_inode_cache
3833235 3828157  99%    0.19K 182535       21    730140K dentry
860224 551785  64%    0.06K  13441       64     53764K kmalloc-64
515688 510872  99%    0.66K  21487       24    343792K proc_inode_cache
168140 123577  73%    0.20K   8407       20     33628K vm_area_struct
136832 108023  78%    0.06K   2138       64      8552K pid
...
```

which looks normal to me.

Creating a rough summary of `lsof`

```
$ sudo lsof | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -h | tail
   6516 1118
   7194 2603
   7884 18727
   8673 19951
  25193 28026
  29637 31798
  38631 15482
  41067 3684
  46800 3626
  75744 17776
```

points to me PID 17776 which is a VirtualBox instance. (Other processes with lots of open files are Chrome, Opera and Thunderbird.) So I wouldn't be overly surprised to later figure out that the major cause of this problem is VirtualBox because that's the only thing that really messes with the kernel.

However, the problem does not go away even if I shutdown virtualbox and kill Chrome, Opera and Thunderbird.

Comment: I originally asked this at Stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/52739906) but was pointed that I should use serverfault or super user instead.

Comment: Note that with modern linux kernel, the `Cached` contains all shared memory, too. For example, if you're running Postgres with huge `shared_buffer` setting, it will be included in `Cached` count even though the kernel cannot re-use that memory without killing all the Postgres processes first.

Comment: Always check `Committed_AS` in `/proc/meminfo`, too. If your committed memory is very high, the kernel will start emitting `MemAvailable` near zero even if you currenty have high `MemFree`, too. This is because technically the kernel is running on COW implementation instead of actually having all the memory it has promised to user mode processes and the kernel code assumes that those already running will start modifying the memory they have in the future so available memory is considered gone.

Comment: The strange part is that MemAvailable is so much less than MemFree. MemAvailable at it's lowest should be MemFree - 200MB or > 5GB where as it is about 2GB

Comment: I nowadays assume that the real problem was high memory fragmentation and zero swap. Especially older Linux kernels (pre 4.0) had major problems automatically defragmenting memory without swap. The memory fragmentation can be inspected via `/proc/buddyinfo`. The `MemAvailable` may be low in these cases because kernel "knows" that it cannot directly use the free memory that's highly fragmented.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any tools I can run to further investigate why this happens?

The discrepancy could be because you are using the wrong calculation.  The answer you linked to does not highlight this, but look at the linked commit message:

> [People] generally do this by adding up "free" and "cached", which was fine ten years ago, but is pretty much guaranteed to be wrong today. It is wrong because `Cached` includes memory that is not freeable as page cache, for example shared memory segments, tmpfs, and ramfs.

The part of `Cached` which is not freeable as page cache (sigh), is counted as  `Shmem` in `/proc/meminfo`.

You can also run `free`, and look in the "shared" column.

Often this is caused by a mounted `tmpfs`.  Check `df -h -t tmpfs`.

Answer (score 2):

As you saw in the article you references, the whole set of calculations around MemAvailable is built around calculating how much memory is free to use without causing any swapping.  You can see in the [actual patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773) that implemented the MemAvailable number that MemAvailable = MemFree - LowWaterMark + (PageCache - min(PageCache / 2, LowWaterMark))

This formula points to the probability that your system's MemAvailable is low because your low water mark, the amount of free memory your system thinks it needs as its working space, is likely very high.  This makes sense in a swapless environment where the system is much more concerned about running out of memory.  You can look at what your current low watermark is:

```
 $ cat /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes
```

I suspect in your case this is quite high.

Almost all the heuristics in Linux's memory management assume you will be operating with some swap space.

Comment: `min_free_kbytes` is `200000` or about 200 MB. Note that even `MemFree` is 3.8 GB higher than `MemAvailable`. In addition, the system has nearly 5 GB in buffers and cache. I have since restarted the workstation and added 2 GB of swap and the issue still continues. Even now I have `MemFree` 1 GB higher than `MemAvailable`. I think the system behavior has changed between kernel version 4.13 and 4.15 so this might be either kernel regression or `MemAvailable` no longer means the same thing it used to mean.

Comment: Thinking this problem a bit more, I think one change that might have triggered the difference is that I used to run VirtualBox 5.1.x and I have upgraded to VirtualBox 5.2.x series. VirtualBox adds custom kernel module which could cause this issue at least in theory.

Comment: I'm currently running Virtualbox 6.0.4 with kernel 4.15.0-46-lowlatency and the problem has not re-appeared even though the system uptime is around 40 days. I guess the problem was caused by Virtualbox or kernel bug.

Comment: Another thing to investigate for similar issues is to check `/proc/buddyinfo`. Sometimes the memory is highly fragmented and kernel will reflect this in `MemAvailable` because it often cannot directly use the free RAM without defragmenting it first.

Answer (score 1):

With modern Linux kernels the `Cached` value contains disk cache *and* all shared memory. As only disk cache can be dropped, it cannot be considered as available memory. [I asked about this on the `linux-mm` mailing list and the general consensus was that the way `Cached` is calculated cannot be changed because of backwards compatibility](https://lore.kernel.org/all/YS0Eq+tNe4Pr7O0X@casper.infradead.org/T/), even though the current computation is a bit problematic for the label "cached". The traditional cached value should be computed as `(Cached - Shmem)` with modern kernels.

Nowadays you should just trust `MemAvailable` to describe the actually available memory in practice. And if you want more detailed breakdown, you should probably get data from `/proc/meminfo` and compute `Free` + `Inactive(file)` + `KReclaimable`. That computation differs from `MemAvailable` in a way that freeing inactive file cache will require IO. Also note that if kernel were to actually free all of `KReclaimable`, the overall throughput would probably suffer quite a bit, too. The `MemAvailable` is a heuristic that tries to guess the available RAM that can be used on top of the current workload without seriously hurting the throughput of the current workload. This is obviously different from theoretical max memory available without crashing the system.